# jQuery Validate adds display:block

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation plugin on my pages
When the field first has jquery error it displays as the following:

```
<label for="fromDate" generated="true" class="error" style="">This field is required.</label>
```

when I correct a validated error it adds the following CSS style to the element.

```
display: none
```

The issue is though when I make the element have an error again it changes the CSS style to the following

```
display: block
```

How can I make it just remove the CSS style instead of switching it to block?

Comment: Since `display:block` is the normal default state of this element, it is functionally identical to removing `display:none`.  In other words, even if you could do what you want, the browser still sees it as `display:block`... no difference.  What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: What is happening is the span that is being created is displayed to the right of the input container the first time. After putting a valid input in (for this case a valid date) the error message disappears.  If I erase the date again it places the span below the input container. I will see if I can make a fiddler that replicates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `display:block` is the normal default state of this element, it is functionally identical to removing `display:none`. In other words, even if you could do what you want, the browser still sees it as `display:block`... no difference. What exactly is the real issue here?

To control where the error is placed, search for `errorPlacement` option [on this page in the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).  Although, you'll probably have the same *issue*, whatever it is.

This shows the `errorPlacement:` option with the default `function`.

```
$("#myform").validate({
    // options,
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
       error.insertAfter(element); // change this to place error message elsewhere
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually this helped me to get closer to the answer.  I tested again and it is not actually fixed by adding the inline-block in the beginning.

Comment: @zmac, not really sure what you're talking about... nobody said anything about _"adding `inline-block` in the beginning"_.  Please append your original posting with a jsFiddle and more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I apologize for not writing out how I arrived at inline block. I tried adding the display:block property to the span to see how it looks before and after.  Adding display:block by itself makes the error message start below the input box.  I found that if I use inline-block it displays where I want it to, the first time, the second time jQuery overrides my inline-block and puts its block back in.

Comment: @zmanc, Please create a jsFiddle that replicates this problem so we can help... otherwise, all I can tell you is that the plugin is functioning normally and I've never seen what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

"How can I make it just remove the CSS style instead of switching it to block?"

You can't unset properties in CSS. You just can set them to some default value.

The display property must be set to some valid value, e.g. `block` and it doesn't get inherited. This is the common way to go in CSS. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display

(also read @Sparky672 comment to understand whats happening here)